# How to find exactly from which class DoModal() is called?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, modal-dialog

I am working in MFC application which has lots of dialog box. I am not able to tell which class or function created this dialog box while debugging.

To illustrate the problem I have created a simple *Dialog based MFC application*. Run it in debug mode and pause the debugging.

I can see DoModal is called in call stack using `CDialog::DoModal()`. How do I understand exactly which function and from which class this `DoModal()` is getting called?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the previous line in the stack?  It's hard to read from what you posted.  Or, have you tried setting a breakpoint in the DoModal code?

Comment: CDialog is MFC class, `CDialog::DoModal` is virtual function. And previous line does not tell me exactly which Dialog is getting called.

Comment: From the little I can see, it looks like you have a dialog based application.  That would imply that the call to DoModal is within the InitInstance method of "CMFCSampleApp".

Comment: You are right, but can you tell me which class is handing dialog. I mean which dialog is exactly shown using DoModal()?

Comment: You should be able to determine that by looking at the InitInstance  method of the "CMFCSampleApp".  If it is a dialog based app, it will have a call to DoModal.  The call will be made from an instantiated class.  Once you have the class, look into the class header of the source code.  It will have the dialog resource that is being loaded.

Comment: What if my application has 100 dialogs, and I want to know which one is getting called right now. Please try it yourself in Visual Studio, you will understand my problem.

Comment: Please post the code for the InitInstance method.

Comment: MSDN: Sometimes your code may break in the message pump. In that case, there is no user code on the call stack.

Comment: Please try it on VS, then we can discuss, this has nothing to do with what is written in InitInstance, all MFC developer knows what is written there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68353/discussion-between-rrirower-and-pranit-kothari).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to find the class if you set a breakpoint in the CDialog constructor.  From the call stack from there you will be able to see what your dialog class is.

Comment: Your answer upto certain extent ease my solution, but it will not solve problem completely. +1 though, because it is good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could set your breakpoint in `CDialog::OnInitDialog()`, which is eventually called by `DoModal()`.

`OnInitDialog` method is almost always overridden by the "leaf" CDialog-derived class (although not necessarily) but more importantly, always chained back.  So just move up the call stack to the "first" call to `OnInitDialog()` and that should reference the class.

If it is not the 'leaf' class, or it was not chained back, @JoeWillcoxson answer still works.